# using c# Insert CSV file into database mapping column

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I need help inserting a CSV data file into an Oracle database.

Here is my problem.

I have a CSV file for which I have some data including a header with ',' delimiters. I also have a database table which has the same header as the name table.

Now, I want to insert the CSV file's data into a database with mapping each column.

For example, abc.csv has a,b,D columns and tableA has A,B,D columns

now a=A ,b=B and d=D

But, the issue is that this CSV column is not fixed. The column position can be changed.

Any ideas?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I am reading csv through stream reader and using index position to get values from each row.. but doing this is somehow a static process. i am searching for a dynamic way to read column header and picking column values based on header

Comment: @ Kshitij Keshri  Can you provide us with an example of your CSV file....?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SQL Bulk Copy Class. http://dotnetmentors.com/c-sharp/bulk-upload-into-sql-server-using-sqlbulkcopy-and-c-sharp.aspx

Assuming the column names in your CSV don't change, you can map columns from your CSV to your table.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. i will try :)